# How to change the color of pixels in a Unity Animation at run-time?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm working on a project in Unity where we have 2D animations. These animations are of space ships where a portion of the ship is purposely colored white.

At run-time we want to be able to change the white part and only the white part of the ship to another color. We've been able to accomplish this for simple sprites but once we implemented the animations we were not able to access the sprite/clip in the animator.

How can we access the clips/sprites in an animation and change the color of pixels?

Comment: You should be able to make/find a color replacement shader based on http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/633203/pixel-color-replacement-in-a-pixel-art-context-.html

Comment: You're looking for palette swapping. It's an old technique used back when limited resources meant you could have more sprites than the resources could allow by changing the colors of existing sprites.

For all the details, you can check out http://www.lynda.com/Unity-2D-tutorials/383045-2.html.